# Is there a way to get this gradient to maybe cycle sideways?

Tags: css

I cannot get the gradient to cycle sideways correctly without a syntax error.

I tried changing the angle for the gradient also. This is a rainbow gradient background that does magic stuffs.

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, 
                              rgba(255,154,0,1) 10%, 
                              rgba(208,222,33,1) 20%, 
                              rgba(79,220,74,1) 30%, 
                              rgba(63,218,216,1) 40%, 
                              rgba(47,201,226,1) 50%, 
                              rgba(28,127,238,1) 60%, 
                              rgba(95,21,242,1) 70%,
                              rgba(186,12,248,1) 80%, 
                              rgba(251,7,217,1) 90%, 
                              rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%) 
    0 0/100% 200%;
    animation: a 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes a {
    to {background-position:0 -200%}
}
```

Comment: what does it mean by sideways??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cycle the gradient sideways instead of vertically, you can modify the `background-position` property in the `@keyframes` rule as well as specifying the direction of the gradient. In this updated code, the `background-position` property is set to `200% 0`, which means the gradient background will scroll horizontally from right to left. Additionally, the `background-size` property is set to `200% 100%` to ensure the background covers the entire width and height of the HTML element. As well as the direction of the gradient being specified by adding `to right,`

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
    rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%,
    rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
    rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
    rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
    rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
    rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
    rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
    rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%
    );

    background-size: 200% 100%;
    animation: a 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes a {
    to {
        background-position: 200% 0;
    }
}
```